# How do I update my forked repo using SourceTree?

Tags: git, github, mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree (with BitBucket) to manage my code.  I have forked a repo, and the parent repo has been updated.

How do I use SourceTree to merge the upstream code into my forked repo?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

First, set up the parent repo:

1. Open your forked repo in SourceTree.
2. Select **Repository** ➫ **Repository Settings…** in the menu (or press <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>).
3. In the **Remotes** pane, press **Add**.
4. Enter any name you like ([often `upstream` or `master`](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/advanced-git-concepts-the-upstream-tracking-branch/)) and the URL / path to the parent repo.
5. Press OK, then OK.

Now, to update:

1. Select Pull in the toolbar.
2. In the "Pull from repository" drop-down, switch from your fork to the repo you just added.
3. Press OK.
4. *(Optional)* Once you pull, you may want to push any new content up to the server.

Comment: I also had to press "Refresh" next to Remote branch to pull. And then select "master" there before I could hit OK.