# How to solve merge conflicts across forks?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have forked my repo, we'll call it repoB from another repo we'll call repoA. Now I don't have permissions to write into repoA.

When I try to create a pull request on repoA to get the latest changes and merge those in to repoB I get a merge conflict error. How do I solve that?

I tried this:

```
git checkout -b repoA master
git pull https:repoA master

git checkout master
git merge --no-ff repoA
git push origin master
```

N.B. I cannot checkout forkA as I don't have write permissions on that.

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos I can compare a branch from Eclipse Git Tool by just checking out the branch I want to compare to. Here I cannot checkout the master branch of the repo that I forked from, so how do I compare?

Comment: Why can't you "checkout the master branch of the repo that I forked from".
This is a read-only action. It should work. Maybe you have a different problem. Like you want to check out the branch with a name that you already have checked out (but with a different upstream)?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First add the upstream remote

```
git remote add upstream https://repoA
git fetch upstream
```

Merge in upstream changes

```
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

Resolve conflicts and push

```
git push origin master
```

Your pull request should automatically update

Comment: I'm having problems with this too but not sure what branch to where.  If I created a pull request of branch-x into branch-y and there are conflicts how do i pull the conflicts to local branch-x so i can fix. Any pointers welcome!

Comment: @v3nt you would fetch the remote with branch-y, then merge branch-y into your branch-x which would throw a bunch of conflicts for resolution. when you've solved those, then commit and push up branch-x to update the PR clearing conflicts.

Comment: For those coming here who want to do this in SourceTree, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13273853/197591) has some good instructions on how to do this.

Comment: @JeffPuckett can you write out the commands for that?